# What is the purpose of having bound class reference return a covariant type?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I'm playing with reflection and I came out with this problem. When using bound class reference via the `::class` syntax, I get a covariant KClass type:

```
fun <T> foo(entry: T) {
    with(entry::class) {
       this // is instance of KClass<out T>
    }
}
```

As I could learn from the docs, this will return the exact type of the object, in case it is instance of a subtype of `T`, hence the variance modifier.
However this prevents retrieving properties declared in the `T` class and getting their value (which is what I'm trying to do)

```
fun <T> foo(entry: T) {
    with(entry::class) {
       for (prop in memberProperties) {
           val v = prop.get(entry) //compile error: I can't consume T
       }
    }
}
```

I found that a solution is using `javaClass.kotlin` extension function on the object reference, to get instead the invariant type:

```
fun <T> foo(entry: T) {
    with(entry.javaClass.kotlin) {
       this // is instance of KClass<T>
    }
}
```

This way, I get both the exact type at runtime and the possibility to consume the type.

Interestingly, if I use a supertype instead of a generic, with the latter method I still get access to the correct type, without the need of variance:

```
class Derived: Base()

fun foo(entry: Base) {
    with(entry.javaClass.kotlin) {
       println(this == Derived::class)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val derived = Derived()
    foo(derived) // prints 'true'
}
```

If I got it correct, `::class` is equal to calling the java `getClass`, which returns a variant type with a wildcard, while `javaClass` is a `getClass` with a cast to the specific type.
Still, I don't get why would I ever need a covariant KClass, when it limits me to only produce the type, given that there are other ways to access the exact class at runtime and use it freely, and I wonder if the more immediate `::class` should return an invariant type by design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for covariance in bound `::class` references is, the actual runtime type of an object the expression is evaluated to might differ from the declared or inferred type of the expression.

Example:

```
open class Base
class Derived : Base()

fun someBase(): Base = Derived()

val kClass = someBase()::class
```

The expression `someBase()` is typed as `Base`, but at runtime it's a `Derived` object that it gets evaluated to.

Typing `someBase()::class` as invariant `KClass<Base>` is simply incorrect, in fact, the actuall result of evaluating this expression is `KClass<Derived>`.

To solve this possible inconsistency (that would lead to broken type-safety), all bound class references are covariant: `someBase()::class` is `KClass<out Base>`, meaning that at runtime `someBase()` might be a subtype of `Base`, and therefore this might be a class token of a subtype of `Base`.

This is, of course, not the case with unbound class references: when you take `Base::class`, you know for sure that it's the class token of `Base` and not of some of its subtypes, so it's invariant `KClass<Base>`.

Comment: I understand what you say. But my point is that if I use someBase().javaClass.kotlin, I still have the correct subtype (Derived) at runtime but also have no variance at compile time, because those extension functions use generics. It seems to me that the ::class syntax could be improved to work like javaClass.kotlin, which is also idiomatically less immediate. It seems to me that they do the same thing, returning a kotlin class, but the latter does a better job while being more verbose

Comment: It's the other way around: `.javaClass` was introduced earlier, and the absence of variance in it was considered a misdesign; `.javaClass` even got deprecated [(in 1.1 RC)](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/02/kotlin-1-1-release-candidate-is-here/), but then, in the 1.1 final release, the deprecation was removed.

Comment: Interesting thing. Yet, if I have to call properties fetched via reflection, I need a receiver and the covariant type won't let me use the bound one. How would you do that in the hypotethic case that `.javaClass` was not available?

Comment: I believe, you would have to make an unchecked cast to do that: `entry::class as KClass<T>` (or cast a reflected function/property you get from it). This looks just as unsafe as it is, because, hypothetically, a `KClass<Derived>` can give you a member that `Base` does not have, and calling that member function/property on an instance of `Base` leads to an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: In fact what `.javaClass`does is doing an unchecked cast. It doesn't seem so unsafe in practice, because when using reflection methods or properties like `memberProperties`, what I get is what the instance has, so I feel safe to use the same receiver instance to obtain its own property's values. That's why I would allow by design a cast on the bound class reference type, because it comes from an instance which is of a definite type at runtime.