# instance::class.java vs. instance.javaClass

Tags: reflection, kotlin

Given Kotlin 1.1. For an `instance` of some class, `instance::class.java` and `instance.javaClass` seem to be nearly equivalent:

```
val i = 0
println(i::class.java) // int
println(i.javaClass) // int
println(i::class.java === i.javaClass) // true
```

There is a subtle difference, however:

```
val c1: Class<out Int> = i::class.java
val c2: Class<Int> = i.javaClass
```

`instance.javaClass` is negligibly shorter, but `instance::class.java` is more consistent with the corresponding usage on a type. While you can use `.javaClass` on some types, the result may not be what you would expect:

```
println(i::class.java === Int::class.java) // true
println(i.javaClass === Int.javaClass) // false
println(Int::class.java === Int.javaClass) // false
println(Int.javaClass) // class kotlin.jvm.internal.IntCompanionObject
```

So, I would argue that it is better to never use `.javaClass` for more consistency. Are there any arguments against that?

Comment: I think I've read somewhere that `javaClass` is to be considered deprecated, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: @marstran Only the overload `KClass<T>.javaClass` has been deprecated. [API reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-class.html)

Answer (score 39):

The difference in these two constructs is that, for an expression `foo` of static (declared or inferred) type `Foo`:

- `foo.javaClass` is typed as `Class<Foo>`
- `foo::class.java` is typed as `Class<out Foo>`

In fact, the latter is more precise, because the actual value that `foo` evaluates to can be an instance of not `Foo` itself but one of its subtypes (and it's exactly what's denoted by the covariant `out Foo`).

As @marstran correctly noted in the comment on the question, `.javaClass` once was considered to be deprecated (see the [Kotlin 1.1 RC announcement](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/02/kotlin-1-1-release-candidate-is-here/)) because it can break type safety (see below), but it was afterwards left as-is because it was widely used and replacing it with the alternative of `::class.java` would require adding explicit unchecked casts in the code.

Also, see the comments under this answer: [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45782580/2196460)

---

Please note that `Int.javaClass` does not denote the type of `Int` but instead is the Java class of the `Int`'s companion object. Whereas `Int::class.java` is an unbound class reference and denotes the type. To get it with `.javaClass`, you need to call it on an `Int` instance, e.g. `1.javaClass`.

---

Here's how exactly `.javaClass` can break type safety. This code compiles but breaks at runtime:

```
open class Foo

class Bar : Foo() {
    val baz: Int = 0
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val someFoo: Foo = Bar()
    val anotherFoo: Foo = Foo()

    val someFooProperty: KProperty1<in Foo, *> = // 'in Foo' is bad
            someFoo.javaClass.kotlin.memberProperties.first()

    val someValue = someFooProperty.get(anotherFoo)
}
```

<sup>This example uses `kotlin-reflect`.</sup>

That's because `someFooProperty` represents a property of `Bar`, not `Foo`, but since it was obtained from `someFoo.javaClass` (`Class<Foo>` then converted to `KClass<Foo>`) the compiler allows us to use it with the `in Foo` projection.

Comment: Why then, I have to use on Android `::class.java` for the case of starting an Activity (example: `startActivity(Intent(context,SomeActivity::class.java)` )? After all, it goes to Java "world", no?