# Kotlin: What is the difference between these variations of referring class type?

Tags: kotlin

PS: Beginner to Kotlin.

What is the difference between these ways of referring to type in Kotlin?

```
Account
Account::class
Account::class.java
Account.javaClass
Account::javaClass
```

Am I missing any other formats of reference related to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [instance::class.java vs. instance.javaClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46674787/instanceclass-java-vs-instance-javaclass)

Comment: It does clarify few things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Account` refers to the class that exists in your code. You should **always** use it (unless you need to pass this class somewhere using reflection) to call constructors, companion object's functions, etc. Also you can use it as generic type.

`Account::class` is a `KClass` object that is the part of Kotlin Reflection API. It stores all information *about* `Account` class - its name, its properties, its annotations, etc - you can get this information in runtime. It allows you to work with classes that are not even in your code - reflection is widely used by many libraries and frameworks, for example, GSON (it uses Java reflection, see below).

`Account::class.java` is a `Class` object that is the part of Java Reflection API. It has the same purpose as `KClass`. Their difference is that `Class` is used in Java reflection libraries (that were created without Kotlin), and `KClass` is used in Kotlin reflection libraries (because it can work with Kotlin-only features like properties, data classes, etc.)

`Account.javaClass` is the same as `Account::class.java`

`Account::javaClass` is `KProperty` object that stores information about `javaClass` property. `KProperty`is the part of Kotlin Reflection API too - through this object you can get annotations on this property, you can check whether it is mutable or not, you can call its getter and setter, etc.