# kotlin bound class reference and generics

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I'm switching to Kotlin for Android, but I'm struggling to understand the behavior of generics and Bound Class References.
In java I can serialize an object using Moshi's lib with the following lines:

```
    Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
    String string = moshi.adapter(CredentialsResponse.class).toJson(body);
```

And in Kotlin:

```
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
    var string = moshi.adapter(CredentialsResponse::class.java).toJson(body)
```

If I want to get the class from an instance, I found two options, but one is not  working, and I can't understand why:
This code works:

```
    fun testStack(body: CredentialsResponse) {
        val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
        var string = moshi.adapter(body.javaClass).toJson(body)
    }
```

but this code shows a type mismatch error

```
    fun testStack(body: CredentialsResponse) {
        val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
        var string = moshi.adapter(body::class.java).toJson(body)
    }
```

[image: Compiler Error]

AFAIK, this call is allowed since 1.1 (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-class-references-since-11), so what am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?
What compiler version do you use?

Comment: done! @TheOperator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a subtle difference between the two:

```
class K
val javaClass: JsonAdapter<K> = moshi.adapter(body.javaClass)
val classJava: JsonAdapter<out K> = moshi.adapter(body::class.java)
```

Note that `body::class.java` is marked with `out`

By calling `moshi.adapter(body::class.java).toJson(body)` you're try to pass `body` as `in` parameter

Answer (score 2):

The difference is, as [@AlexeySoshin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5985853/alexey-soshin) noted, that the unbound class reference `Foo::class` is typed with the exact type of the referenced class `KClass<Foo>`, and the bound one is typed with an `out`-projection: `KClass<out Foo>`.

There is a strong reason for this difference. When you reference a class by its name, you can be sure that the class token the reference evaluates to designates exactly the referenced type.

But, when you get a bound class reference for an expression typed as `Foo`, the expression may evaluate to an instance of `Foo`'s subtype, and the correct type for the type token is `KClass<out Foo>`, meaning exactly that the actual type argument may be `Foo` or its subtype.

See this answer for another detailed explanation of the difference between bound and unbound class references: [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45782580/2196460)

Comment: Yeah, `T:Any` was a bit mind-bending at first glance :)