# Kotlin: Function with generic parameter class

Tags: android, kotlin

how to create a function that receives in parametre any type of class?

I want to print the fields of the class passed in parameters and their values
Here is my code test but it does not work:

```
fun saveInPreference(klass: Any) {
    for (prop in klass::class.memberProperties) {
        println("${prop.name}") //Print field name of the class
        println("${prop.name} = ${prop.get(prop.name)}") // Error not work, not get value of fields
    }

}
```

thanks

Comment: This doesn't use generics though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the API that you are using is just a little more type-safe than is required by your use case. In fact, the type of a `prop` that you get from the `memberProperties` is an `out`-projected type, so you cannot just pass an instance of the type that it was obtained from without capturing the type. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782409/what-is-the-purpose-of-having-bound-class-reference-return-a-covariant-type) for an explanation.

As for your use case, it's enough to use a less type-safe API, `call(obj)` instead of `get(obj)`:

```
for (prop in klass::class.memberProperties) {
    /* ... */
    println("${prop.name} = ${prop.call(prop.name)}") 
}
```